# matplotlib axes.fill_between() raises `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types` for float arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I ran into this problem when I tried to fill the area between the x axis and the function graph with the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

s1_norm_x = np.array([0, l-b, l-b, l])
s1_norm_y = np.array([G_x, G_x, 0, 0])

figure, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
ax_norm, ax_quer, ax_bieg = axs
ax_norm.set_xticks([0, l-b, l])

ax_norm.set_xlabel('x')
ax_norm.set_ylabel("Normalkraft - N(x) [kN]")
ax_norm.plot(s1_norm_x, s1_norm_y, color='blue')
ax_norm.fill_between(s1_norm_x, s1_norm_y, facecolor = 'red', alpha = 0.3)

plt.show()
```

The values of l, b, G_x, respectively: `l=1.1, b=0.8, G_x=-3.2031250000`.

I tried replacing `s1_norm_x` and `s1_norm_y` with arrays of integers of the same length (4), which solved the problem in that no error has been raised and the filling was correctly plotted, but then it wasn't aligned to the function graph.

Please, help me solve this problem.

Full error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 11
      9 ax_norm.set_ylabel("Normalkraft - N(x) [kN]")
     10 ax_norm.plot(s1_norm_x, s1_norm_y, color='blue')
---> 11 ax_norm.fill_between(s1_norm_x, s1_norm_y, facecolor = 'red', alpha = 0.3)
     13 plt.show()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1442, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1439 @functools.wraps(func)
   1440 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1441     if data is None:
-> 1442         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1444     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1446                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:5431, in Axes.fill_between(self, x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, step, **kwargs)
   5429 def fill_between(self, x, y1, y2=0, where=None, interpolate=False,
   5430                  step=None, **kwargs):
-> 5431     return self._fill_between_x_or_y(
   5432         "x", x, y1, y2,
   5433         where=where, interpolate=interpolate, step=step, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:5336, in Axes._fill_between_x_or_y(self, ind_dir, ind, dep1, dep2, where, interpolate, step, **kwargs)
   5332         kwargs["facecolor"] = \
   5333             self._get_patches_for_fill.get_next_color()
   5335 # Handle united data, such as dates
-> 5336 ind, dep1, dep2 = map(
   5337     ma.masked_invalid, self._process_unit_info(
   5338         [(ind_dir, ind), (dep_dir, dep1), (dep_dir, dep2)], kwargs))
   5340 for name, array in [
   5341         (ind_dir, ind), (f"{dep_dir}1", dep1), (f"{dep_dir}2", dep2)]:
   5342     if array.ndim > 1:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py:2366, in masked_invalid(a, copy)
   2364     cls = type(a)
   2365 else:
-> 2366     condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
   2367     cls = MaskedArray
   2368 result = a.view(cls)

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: The code you provide works for me without any error. Maybe it's a bug of your `matplotlib`. Which is your version? Mine is `3.6.3.`; you can get it by `print(mpl._get_version())`

Comment: Review the `shape` and `dtype` of `s1_norm_x`,  `s1_norm_y`

Comment: The problem was with the dtype of `s1_norm_y`, more precisely, with `G_y`, which was of `sympy`'s `sympy.core.numbers.Float` type, not Python's built-in float.

Comment: mpl version was `3.7.0.`, but in the end that didn't have to do with the problem

Comment: Yes, trying to use `sympy` objects in a numpy array produces `object` dtype arrays, which are quite limited when it comes to math and testing from things like `inf`.  Since you didn't show `sympy` in either the imports or the tags, we couldn't have guessed that problem (though I'm not surprised).